# Azure DevOps git clone with SSH fails - no match: SSHBlackbox.10

Tags: git, ssh, azure-devops

I am running on Linux. I created a repository on Azure DevOps and I am trying to clone it using SSH. It used to work before but not anymore. I made sure the ssh key is in .ssh folder, I added the public key to Azure DevOps SSH Keys. I also edited the config to make sure it is using the right key. yet when I run `git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/xxx/xxx/xxx` it stays not doing anything for a long time then it throws the error

```
Cloning into 'xxxxxxx'...
Connection reset by 51.104.26.0 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I ran this command to debug `ssh -v -T git@ssh.dev.azure.com` it showed the below and stayed also not doing anything for a while.

What could be the problem? Anyone can help solving this?

```
OpenSSH_8.4p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/profile/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/profile/.ssh/config line 10: Applying options for ssh.dev.azure.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ssh.dev.azure.com [51.104.26.13] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/profile/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/profile/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSHBlackbox.10
debug1: no match: SSHBlackbox.10
debug1: Authenticating to ssh.dev.azure.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

Comment: "connection reset" means they dropped their "end" of the "phone call" by just abruptly hanging up, without first going through the cordial-good-bye sequence. The debug output you show doesn't say why they did that, and the fact that they are just rudely hanging up on you means you can't find out why, because only they can tell you why and they're not telling you why they won't tell you why, much less telling you why. So use some *other* method to get hold of them (e.g., call the support folks on an actual phone).

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved disconnecting my corporate VPN.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).